# How to read / write arraylist of custom object into internal storage in android

Tags: android

In our application , we are getting pdf files from server. We store those files such as its content , file size , no.of pages etc. into array list. Now we are storing this array list into DB, sometimes we are getting out of memory error. How we can store this array list into internal storage for security.

Below is code:

```
ArrayList<ScriptBean> scriptBeanArr = getScripts(scriptIds); ArrayList<ScriptBean> tempList = DbConnection.getdbObject(activityContext).updateScriptPdfToDB(scriptBeanArr));
```

Comment: Please give snippet of your code so that we can suggest you something.

Comment: In our code we have custom obj as scriptBean , which has multiple properties such as content , no of pages,file size etc. From server we are getting multiple pdf files. so we are storing into arraylist of scriptBean object and this arraylist we are storing into DB. Below is code:                                              ArrayList<ScriptBean> scriptBeanArr = getScripts(scriptIds);           ArrayList<ScriptBean> tempList = DbConnection.getdbObject(activityContext).updateScriptPdfToDB(scriptBeanArr));

Answer (score 0):

You should let the class you'd like to write to disk implement Serializable. Then, serialize the class and write the bytes to a file on disk. Then you can read the bytes from the disk and deserialize them into an object.